# What is the best way to parse strings and nested brackets in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a program that takes a regular string with quotations and nested brackets and breaks them down in a list.

So far I am using this RegEX : `@"[\""].+?[\""]|\{.*\}|(?=\()(?:(?=.*?\((?!.*?\1)(.*\)(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?\)(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)[^(]*(?=\2$)|[^ ]+"`

What i want it to do is this:
`if (eval (date day) == "14") {print "Today is the 14th"} else {print "It is not the 14th"}`

```
if
(eval (date day) == "14")
{print "Today is the 14th"}
else
{print "It is not the 14th"}
```

but it returns as

```
if
(eval (date day) == "14")
{print "Today is the 14th"} else {print "It is not the 14th"}
```

I had this problem with the parenthesis and found a solution online but when I tried to change it to work with the {} it doesn't work.

I read online that RegEX doesn't work but I have not found a new solution. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: What if you have `if (eval (date day) == "14") {print "Today is the 14th :)}"} else {print "It is not the 14th :( :{{{"}`?

Comment: I would not recommend doing regex parsing. Might be worth giving [Pidgin](https://github.com/benjamin-hodgson/Pidgin) or [Superpower](https://github.com/datalust/superpower) a look. They are much nicer then regex,  Superpower is a bit nicer to use and pidgin is faster.

Comment: Seems like something that you could write a custom parser for. Count the opening brackets and closing brackets (and keep track of their indexes), then create a bunch of substrings. It's not clear to me what you want to do if one of these special characters is inside a string, though. Do you ignore it? If so, even more reason to roll your own.

Comment: How uniform is the input going to be? Will it always be IF..THEN..ELSE, or could there be multiple statements in each block, no ELSE clause, etc?

Comment: And, what are you going to do with the list of strings? Maybe there's a way to achieve what you want without having to create this list first.

Answer (score 1):

If the delimiters are () and {} and you want to ignore string content that could contain
delimiters you just need to use a balanced text regex.

```
(?:[^(){}]+|(?:(?:(?'opP'\()(?>[^()"]+|"[^"]*")*)+(?:(?'clP-opP'\))(?>[^()"]+|"[^"]*")*?)+)+(?(opP)(?!))|(?:(?:(?'opBr'\{)(?>[^{}"]+|"[^"]*")*)+(?:(?'clBr-opBr'\})(?>[^{}"]+|"[^"]*")*?)+)+(?(opBr)(?!)))
```

C# sample

```
Regex RxParts = new Regex(@"(?:[^(){}]+|(?:(?:(?'opP'\()(?>[^()""]+|""[^""]*"")*)+(?:(?'clP-opP'\))(?>[^()""]+|""[^""]*"")*?)+)+(?(opP)(?!))|(?:(?:(?'opBr'\{)(?>[^{}""]+|""[^""]*"")*)+(?:(?'clBr-opBr'\})(?>[^{}""]+|""[^""]*"")*?)+)+(?(opBr)(?!)))" );
string test_sample = @"if (eval (date day) == ""14"") {print ""Today is the 14th""} else {print ""It is not the 14th""}";

Match M = RxParts.Match(test_sample);
while ( M.Success )
{
    string strM = M.Value.Trim();
    if ( strM.Length > 0 )
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", strM);
    M = M.NextMatch();
}
```

output

```
if
(eval (date day) == "14")
{print "Today is the 14th"}
else
{print "It is not the 14th"}
```